# What keywords are important to speedup the code in C++?

Tags: c++, fortran

I'm porting to C++ and adding a lot of functionality to a numerical application written in Fortran 77. While I hate F77, I have to admit that the thing goes very fast. Now, I'm implementing practically the same structure and algorithm, but nevertheless the difference in the execution time is noticeable. Not big, but it's there. And I'm wondering, could it be that I need to pass extra information to the compiler? The only related information that I've been able to find is a recommendation to use the **restrict** key word which is supported by g++, but that's all. Hence, my question: Are there anymore keywords important to speedup code in C++ in numerical applications? or maybe compiler directives?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using optimization? Try `g++ -O3`. I don't know anything about your program, however you also want to make sure that you pass references instead of objects (which invokes the copy constructor) to functions.

Comment: @Mike yes, I'm using -O3, but had not thought about passing references... one item to check for. Thanks.

Comment: If it's not big, is it even a problem? Are your cpu time savings going to offset your programmer time costs?

Comment: @Mike Steinert: Since FORTRAN is based a lot on processing arrays. It should be noted that passing an array will not result in a copy. The array will decay naturally into a pointer (which is like FORTRAN behavior (I think (that's how I remember but it has been a long time))).

Comment: I don't believe restrict is supported by standard C++, it is a C99 keyword. GCC likely introduces it to C++ as a non-standard extension, and it is usually a bad idea to use GCC extensions instead of sticking to the standard.

Comment: there's no keyword in C++ which says "match Fortrain performance on this code with no further input from me". You, the programmer, have to understand your code, understand the language, and understand the compiler, in order to achieve a speedup.

Comment: Fortran compilers are still optimising numeric code better than C++. Little can be done to offset this effect.

Comment: Not a keyword, but there are excellent high performance libraries for numerical processing in C/C++, e.g. Intel's IPP or Eigen 3. Maybe you can use one of these.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I do not believe that you should focus your optimizations looking for magic keywords, but here goes some tips:

1. "**inline**" might do wonders in numerical apps if you  have many short numerical functions
2. Be careful when copying values all around when you could use a reference. This sounds basic but if you have many classes that are copy/assignment compatible your code could be hiding some copies. Make sure your constructors are defined with the "**explicit**" keyword, that way your compiler will show you where implicit copies are done.
3. Give C++11 a try. There are some interesting optimizations. There are more things that are solved statically. Also one very interesting thing for your case is the [rvalue reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors) optimization. It is a very important optimization on the return value of functions. You will notice that a lot if you overload operators, which you will do if you operate different units and try to structure your old code.
4. There are lots of things that can be done with STL and really interesting template metaprograming, but that is a whole different level to what most people is used to.
5. Do not rely too much on your compiler optimizations. C++ syntax is well known to make life easier for low-level programmers and a nightmare for compiler designers. That is one of the reasons for which good static analyzers took so long to appear. I know that Scott Mayers made that comment and how C++11 improvements will help to get better tools, but cannot quote where he did.
6. On the line with compilers... do not expect to get [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) and overall paralel optimizations. Compilers are really bad at it and unless you get your hands dirty with some library for it, your code will target only one core, one thread of your machine.
7. It might sound silly but the keyword "**const**" is really important. If you make clear that some value does not change, the compiler will apply a whole extra set of optimizations. Detecting if a variable could be considered const takes some extra parsing that most compilers do not perform not even with optimizations maxed out. Related with this for example, if your loops do not seem to have a clear/constant end, the compiler will not unroll them (or maybe not as good as it could)

However I wonder why you are migrating from Fortran77 to C++. Fortran sure is an old language, but it is the king for mathematics no matter how ugly it looks, the best way to deal with old code is building a good layer and operate it from outside with the new infrastructure and language you want. It is easier said than done, because sure you will have still to fix some Fortran code in order to make it easier to operate from outside.

If you decide to go on with C++ at least you will get much nicer libraries for multithreading (and that is one of the biggest improvements of C++11) where Fortran lags behind. Try to avoid CUDA if not absolutely necessary, it is really good and mature but focused on NVIDIA. I would keep an eye on OpenCL

Be aware that there is one huge difference for Math. In C++ (like most languages), the values of a matrix are stored as a set of rows while Fotran stores them as a set of columns. This makes a huge difference on the best memory usage of your algorithms. Hence if your algorithms are optimized for Fortran, their loops will target columns instead of rows. ([look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)) That is how seriously Fortran optimized for Mathematics goes.

One final concern. You want to use C++ and not Fotran77. Because you can get a better abstraction and design? Well, that is a good reason, but please, be wary of the market obsession with object oriented programming. It is a good thing, but not a silver bullet. A GUI for example should always be object oriented, but if you do lots of math and move huge amounts of memory, some aspect oriented style would be nice. Even better for your domain problem, have a look at [data oriented design](http://gamesfromwithin.com/data-oriented-design) as an alternative to object oriented design (and see one case where OOP fails)

Comment: WRT #1: I was under the impression that many modern compilers did this optimization automatically, and are now quite good at it. I admit haven't done C/C++ myself for a while, but this is what I've been hearing...

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, and so I felt compelled to add point 5 and 6 ... ;-)  In the case of inline they do a good job. On one hand the programmer can abuse and have inline when the compiler would not use them, on the other some compilers ignore the user completly, like the keyword "register" and I believe that most compilers today completely ignore it.

Comment: I like the `const` optimization. The compiler can go to the extreme with pruning the syntax tree when it knows the value of something prior to execution :)

Comment: Regarding #7: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/081.htm

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel, that is a great link, it is specially reliable coming from Herb Sutter. I also think that const is for humans. It ease understanding code making clear which variables will change or which functions change the object. Notice that he is asking for keywords and I tried to give him some. Still some compilers could do something. The problem is that every compiler optimize different. Also using "explicit" will for sure not optimize anything, but helps pointing interesting spots. The real value is at the end, about how Fortran operates on a matrix and data oriented design

Answer (score 12):

If you had to narrow it down to one keyword, it would probably be `template`. Unfortunately, applying that (at all well) will require some study. Applying it as well as possible (e.g., using expression templates) will require quite a lot of study.

For some ideas of how to write competitive numerical code in C++, you might want to look at some existing libraries such as [blitz++](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/) and [Boost uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm).

Answer (score 10):

Your code will hardly become faster magically by ***sprinkling a few keywords here and there***. And simply copying algorithms from one language to another (if that's indeed what you are doing) is never going to help. Speed correlates with

1. a ***good design***, and
2. selectively applied ***optimizations*** based on careful ***profiling***.

As for design: The one thing that made C++ equal FORTRAN's performance was the invention of ***expression templates*** by Todd Veldhuizen for [his blitz++ library](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/).

Answer (score 8):

The first thing you should do is profile, to see which specific piece of code is responsible for the slowdown.

As far as the keywords, `inline` might be a good one to use.

Comment: +1 for profiling first - blind optimisation is a complete waste of time

Comment: It would be nice to see the reason for the down vote.

Answer (score 5):

One thing to remember when porting from Fortran to C++ is the different array layout: Fortran, by default, uses column-major layout, C and C++ row-major. When your program relies heavily on linear algebra (like all Fortran programs seem to do), the different cache behaviour will make a major difference.

If that seems to be the problem (read: your profiler shows you are spending considerable time in linear algebra), try using a decent LA library like `Eigen` with matrices in column-major layout.

Answer (score 1):

These are good answers, but it's quite possible both the Fortran and the C++ versions contain substantial room for speedup, so you wouldn't really expect them to be exactly the same speed now.

Assuming you want either one to be as fast as possible for a given machine and input load, there is a countable infinity of programs that do the job, and some program(s) that take less time than all the others.
What you want to do is remove unnecessary activities until the program approaches that optimal shortness of time, regardless of language.

[Here's how I do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024), and here's an example of [seriously aggressive performance tuning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773).

If I can just give examples, in C++ (using MFC) [here is a case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916985/what-is-boilerplate-code-hot-code-and-hot-spots/7923574#7923574) where something you wouldn't normally worry about, array indexing, turns out to cost 40% of the time and can be done better. In an example I did using stl vectors, the cost was even higher.

Similarly in Fortran, I was tuning some code that used the LAPACK library, which one would think would be about as finely optimized as possible.
Chances are it is, for large matrices and a small number of calls.
However, for small matrices and a large number of calls, guess what it was spending a *heavy* fraction of its time doing.
It was calling a function to do string compares to see what the options were in calling the math functions.
For example, DGEMM is a general routine to do matrix multiplication & scaling.
It's first two arguments are CHARACTER*1 flags that tell it whether either input matrix is transposed.
For small matrices, calling a function to test those flags is a major percent of the time, and could clearly be eliminated by writing a more specialized routine.

The only generality you can draw from these examples is that you need an effective diagnostic (like random-pausing) to tell what the problem is at each stage of performance tuning. The problems you find will undoubtedly be different from these examples, but in every case the only way you know what to fix is to have the program itself tell you.

Once you get rid of the extra stuff being done in the program that exists to make some unspecified general coding easier,
then you can turn the compiler's optimizer loose to do its own level of cycle-squeezing (assuming speed is your major concern).

Answer (score 1):

Most of it is going to be in the design of the rewrite.  I've done F to C and F to C++ several times for commercial products and the biggest boogymen were:

- Beware of allocation operations in node-based standard library iterators.
- Knock out any pass by reference (pointers), remember that Fortran has the no-aliasing rule for pointers.  C and C++ do not, so if you end up with a function that looks like this:

  ```
  int some_function(int* a, int* b)
  {

       ...code...
       int some_intermediate_value = *a + *b;
       int other_value = *a + 7;
       ...and other code referencing b and a...

  }
  ```

...it will fetch a and b every time (because of aliasing rules).  Solvable by either changing the function signature and uses, or by copying to local temporaries inside the function (useful when doing a BIG refactor where it's tough to grab so many changes at once).